# When is it legal to type-pun using a pointer-to-a-pointer in C?

Tags: c, pointers, type-conversion

In a C program I have a struct

```
typedef struct {
    void *payload; // opaque, real type known to callbacks

         ... some stuff ...
} MiddleMan;
```

To create some veneer of type-safety I might create getters and setters

```
CbData *get_cb_data(const MiddleMan *mm){ return mm->payload; }   
void set_cb_data(MiddleMan *mm, CbData *cbd){ mm->payload = cbd; }
```

Or I can try to do it with a single, pointer-based accessor

```
CbData **cb_data(MiddleMan *mm){return (CbData**)&mm->payload;}
```

Now the second solutions looks dodgier than the first, and it also restricts users to non-const `mm` even if they only want to read.  But my question is whether it is even legal C?

I'm fairly sure you can get away with it on any architecture where `void*` is the same size & format as `CbData*`.  But can anyone give clear reasoning why this is (or is not) valid in general?

Comment: This is legal in C. `void *` and `CbData *` are always the same size - both are pointer type. Sorry but I do not understand why there is a question on the validity of this `**` implementation you wrote above.

Comment: On some weird architectures, the size of pointers varies depending on what they point to.  `void *` is supposed to be big enough to cover all possibilities, but `CbData *` can be smaller, depending on what `CbData` actually is.

Comment: can you please give some examples of those weird architectures? Really curious.

Comment: @ManojAwasthi happily I don't know of any of them (I heard of them on `comp.lang.c`).  Perhaps some old supercomputers put numeric vectors in a separate universe from bookkeeping integers.  16-bit DOS/Windows programs had the distinction between `near` and `far`, but that was independent of the type being pointed to.

Answer (score 4):

Generally, you shouldn't do that. A `void**` may have the different alignment requirement with `CbData**`. An explicit cast may produce the different address.

C standard 6.2.5.27:

> A pointer to void shall have the same representation and alignment
>   requirements as a pointer to a character type.39) Similarly, pointers
>   to qualified or unqualified versions of compatible types shall have
>   the same representation and alignment requirements. All pointers to
>   structure types shall have the same representation and alignment
>   requirements as each other. All pointers to union types shall have the
>   same representation and alignment requirements as each other. Pointers
>   to other types need not have the same representation or alignment
>   requirements.

Comment: however 6.3.2.3 says: `A pointer to void may be converted to or from a pointer to any incomplete or object
type. A pointer to any incomplete or object type may be converted to a pointer to void
and back again; the result shall compare equal to the original pointer.` ...wouldn't this apply here?

Comment: So far this sounds correct, but I am waiting for other opinions before I accept it.  Since `void *` is the most general pointer type, `void **` will have the strictest alignment, and thus the cast to `(CbData**)` will be a pure re-intrepret.  My guess is that the thing is illegal, but works even on the weirdest architectures.

Comment: @msam that is talking about explicit type conversions between pointer values, whereas I am punning on the address of those pointers.  That's why things are not clear.